# My content updates won't display instantly in the front-end. What's the reason?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, cache, global-configuration

I am using joomla to create my website. Everything is working well, except one problem that  occurred recently.

I am changing/updating content in the joomla backend and saving. But any change I do will not appear in the front-end instantly. It is taking time.

What is the reason? Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to my other answer, there can be a few other reasons that can cause a delay to what you see on the front-end of a website against your changes in the backend.

1. **Your computer**. Starting from your computer, it's possible that your browser has also cached a page and may show you the cached content. So, usually in such cases keep in mind to also clear your browser's cache.
2. **Hosting Providers Servers**. Some hosting providers have also implemented caching mechanisms into their server, which will also causes a delay to update the front-end content of webpage. I can recall from GoDaddy's hosting, a feature called "Website Speed-up" or something like that, that is serving cached content.
3. **Server configuration and expire headers.** It's possible that there is set an extended expire headers value for html content on the server configuration or the .htaccess.
4. **Content delivered through CDN**. It's also possible and depending on the configuration settings between your website and the CDN, that the CDN platform still delivers previous cached content and has not been updated accordingly to the current content of a webpage.
5. **Other network or proxy caching mechanisms**. In some caches it's also possible that the content of a webpage is cached in the network between a browser and the server of the website. Especially if other previous settings as described previously are involved, that has instructed any intermediate servers to cache a page.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this due to the **Cache** Mechanisms.

In this wikipedia article you will see that caching is an important computing feature that is used widely. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)

When enabled in Joomla, it delivers to the users a stored view of the web page, same as it was previously displayed, so it won't have to ask the database and reload content, thus it can speed up the speed load of a website and save resources on the server.

### JOOMLA CACHE

Joomla provides the following caching levels:

#### a. Page cache

It stores a full copy of the rendered page. It is controlled by a **system plugin** : **Plugins Manager -> System Cache plugin**, and it is disabled by default. It applies only to non-logged in users.

#### b. View cache

It stores part of the page. It is also disabled by default and can be accessed in the **Global configuration** -> System.

It provides 2 caching ways: **Conservative** and **Progressive** cache.
Progressive caching caches the content for each unique visitor, while Conservative caching delivers the same cached content to all visitors.

There you can also control the time that a cached content should be remained, before it is considered expired and therefore replaced with a new one. If the content updates are frequent you may want to set this to a low value.

#### c. Module Caching

It also partially stores content of the page, per module. It is controlled from within each module, usually in the advanced section of module settings. It is recommended to be enabled only for modules that contain static content.

When cache is enabled, Joomla stores the cached content inside the Cache folder of its filesystem ( siteroot/cache/ ).

#### 3rd Party Caching Extensions

Apart of the core cache functionality, there are 3rd party extensions that allows more control over how the cache should work on a Joomla site.
**[Joomla Cache Extensions in JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/cache)**

#### Clearing Caches

The cached content can be deleted/emptied, if you want to remove all cached content and force joomla to reload all content fresh from the database. Sometimes **clearing caches**, it helps resolving display or other issues, so it's common practice to **clear or disable the cache** when something doesn't look or work as expected, to ensure that is not a caching issue.

> **To clear Joomla Cache go at:**
> **System** -> **Maintenance** ->  **Clear Cache** / **Purge Expired Caches**.

**Clear Cache** will remove all cached content and the system will have to regenerate/reload it at the next page load. This might make the next load of a page to take a bit more time, since it will also have to create the new cached files, but after the next load the pages will load faster again.

**Purge Expired Caches** will only remove items that have expired. This will check each cached file by file if it has expired and will delete only these files, therefore if the website is big, it can be resource intensive during the purging process.

**[Nonumbers Cache Cleaner](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/cache/9495)** extension is a system plugin that can be set to clean up caches within specified timeframes, or after "**Saving**" anything in the backend.